# Ionic 2 Tabs in the top and the bottom

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2, components, ionic3

I would like to make a `tabs component` which has some tabs in the top of the screen and some in the bottom, is there a way to achieve this?

Something like this:

[image]

I tried using two instances but I couldn't make it and I guess it's gonna be very difficult to synchronize between them.

Any Ideas?

Comment: i am not understanding can you explain me

Answer (score 16):

You can have TabsComponent in top of your page as well. 
Assuming that you have imported and declared TabsComponent 
All you have to do is , add this attribute to your **app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{tabsPlacement: 'bottom'})
],
```

This actually only lets you to change the position of Tabs bar.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine a tabs layout (tabs at the bottom) and add a toolbar at the top of each page with a few [Segment](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/segment/Segment/) components like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="topTab" color="secondary">
      <ion-segment-button value="camera">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="bookmark">
        <ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

That way you'd have tabs at the bottom (tabs component) and tabs at the top (header with segments). I don't know if that makes sense in the context of your app, but in terms of UI the result would be pretty similar to the screenshot provided.

Comment: Hmmm yeah possible, good idea! I didn't think about that... Thank you for ur quick answer

Comment: There are some cases in which it would be a bad idea to use ``segment`` i think. For instance if I want have an ``http`` request in each one of the tabs which gets called only  after ``ionViewDidLoad`` . This solution send all ``http`` request even without opening the segment. I had a similar situation , I chose ``tabs inside tabs`` method which works well. And I have animation and other ionic page callbacks still available.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ionic 2 or 3 here is the way-

1. Open  `src\app\app.module.ts` file
2. Pass `tabsPlacement:'bottom'` as an object value to the 
   `onicModule.forRoot()` function.
3. Pass object as the second argument.
4. Can use `'top'` in place of `'bottom'` to appear at the top
   Hope it will work for you!!!

code [source here](http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-place-ionic-2-tabs-at-the-bottom-or-top-of-the-screen/).